# How to add numbers in a listBox

Tags: c#

My program is supposed to generate 24 random numbers then add them all together and display them.

I've gotten them to do everything, except I can't get the first 24 numbers to add.
I tried moving the statement that collects the numbers but it didn't work.
Im not sure how to go forward.

```
int x = 0;
int number = 0;
int i = 0;

while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
{
    number += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i++]);
}

totaltextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(number);

Random ran = new Random();

for(x = 0;x <= 23; x++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(ran.Next(0,100)));
}
fileNumbers.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Comment: What errors you get?

Comment: From what you have posted it should work. Maybe there is something else in your code that overrides this behavior

Comment: I dont get an errors, it just displays 0 in my textbox. This is all of my code besides the exit button.

Comment: Only one 0 or 24 zeroes?

Comment: you have 2 textboxes, which one do you mean?
totaltextbox will be 0 because at the time you call the while loop, the listbox is empty.

Comment: Only a single 0. Sorry, for my total textbox

Comment: do you use `listBox1` anywhere else in the code?

Comment: The problem is obvious here. You try to add the numbers from the list box items before creating the items.

Comment: I moved the entire while statement below where i created my random numbers and it works.

Comment: @Niomi than it means you explained the issue wrong since the listbox is not affected by that while. Only the TextBoxes are affected by that change.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you set your totaltextbox text too early. That way the listbox is empty when you try to accumulate the values.

Try this:

```
Random ran = new Random();

for (var x = 0; x <= 23; x++)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(ran.Next(0, 100)));
}

var number = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Select(Int32.Parse).Sum();
var count = listBox1.Items.Count;
```

I also replaced your while loop with a LINQ-Expression. Also note, that in c# you can declare `for`-variables like in my example code. No need to declare them for the whole method (unless you want to use them after the for loop for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `for` and `while` loop. if not, it cant take `listBox1.Items.Count`.

```
int x = 0;
int number = 0;
int i = 0;
Random ran = new Random();
for (x = 0; x <= 23; x++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(ran.Next(0, 100)));
}
while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
{
    number += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i++]);
}

totaltextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(number);
fileNumbers.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. However I will add my solution which avoids some back and forth conversions and reduces iterations:

```
Random ran = new Random();
int total = 0;
for (int x = 0; x <= 23; x++)
{
 int rn = ran.Next(0, 100);
 total += rn;
 listBox1.Items.Add(rn.ToString());
}

totaltextBox.Text = total.ToString();
```